# Using Mysql and sql server from python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

I need to write a python application with use both of the mysql and sql server is there 
a general python module or library that can access both mysql and sql server as DBI with perl or should i use 2 libraries and if yes which libraries do you recommend .

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org).  You will probably need some time getting into it, but it is invaluable once you have covered the basics.

SQLAlchemy acts as a frontend to other, database-specific libraries using the Python DB-API -- but beyond this, it provides a query builder library that abstracts out differences between databases' SQL syntax and permits programmatic query construction while still offering the full power of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Python RDBMS modules implement [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: Could you provide me which RDBMS modules are they and if they supported on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for which connection drivers to use, I believe the only one that well work for both [MySQL ([driver here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)) and SQLServer (native to windows/[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) for linux) is [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/).  @igor has the right idea, though, use SQLAlchemy, you can connect to each [database using different engines](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dbengine.html#supported-dbapis), but use the same code to interact with both.